# Filter an ArrayList of objects based on more than one field

Tags: java, class, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

So this is my  class:

```java
class A {
    private int id;
    private TimeStamp startDate;
    private TimeStamp endDate;
    private String source;
}
```

I have a `List<A> list1`

So in this list if any two objects have same `startDate` and same `source` then I need to select the one with higher `endDate`. How can I achieve it?

My current implementation:(it checks only `startDate` and not `source` and then select higher `endDate` value)

```java
Collection<A> result =
            
list1.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getStartDate,
                                  Function.identity(),
                                  (a, b) -> a.getEndDate().after(b.getEndDate()) ? a : b))
        .values();
```

How can I extend this code to check for source also or any other implementation to do the same is also fine...

Comment: Collect, grouping by source, then use your current code on each value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a method in `A` which generates a `String` key based on the `startDate` and `source`. Then you could use this in `toMap`:

```java
class A {
    private int id;
    private TimeStamp startDate;
    private TimeStamp endDate;
    private String source;
    
    public String getKey() {
        return this.startDate.toString() + source;
    }
}

list1.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getKey,
                                  Function.identity(),
                                  (a, b) -> a.getEndDate().after(b.getEndDate()) ? a : b))
        .values();
```

Comment: That is a nice solution. Can we take an approach without modifying this class?

Comment: @IshanArora Yes you could take out the method to another class (maybe a utility class) which you are free to modify(ex : `YourClass`)and make it `static` and pass object of `A` as parameter. Then inside `toMap` instead of `A::getKey` invoke `YourClass:: getKey`. Or you don't need the method itself, and inline it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Getter
class A {
    private int id;
    private TimeStamp startDate;
    private TimeStamp endDate;
    private String source;
}

    list1.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a.getStartDate()+a.getSource(),
                    Function.identity(),
                    (a, b) -> a.getEndDate().after(b.getEndDate()) ? a : b))
            .values();
```